# Should I self-submit forms or submit to an external file?

Tags: forms, coldfusion, submit

I'm fairly new to programming - specifically Coldfusion, and I'm curious if it makes a difference whether I submit a form to the page it's on and process the results there, or if it should be submitted to an external file for processing, and then redirected from there?

Answer (score 2):

It can make a difference. When I first started programming I would often do things like:

`myform.cfm(get/post) ->  myformresults.cfm(get/post)`

At first it seemed like this was a reasonable approach. The form and the form results often look quite different. They interact with DBs quite differently. In the long term this has not turned out to a good approach. Now I typically:

`myform.cfm(get) -> myform.cfm(post)`

**Reason 1:**
If the form when it was posted, had issues I am already in the right place to re populate it.

**Reason 2:**
HTTP gets are intended to get data without manipulation. HTTP posts are intended to manipulate data. This keeps with the already established pattern

**Reason 3:**
There is less to debug. because there are fewer combinations of pages and methods

**Reason 4:** 
It is often useful in programming to see what is common, and not what is different. You may very well find that the your `myformresults.cfm` page really is quite similar to `myform.cfm`

**Reason 5:**
.Net developers are already doing this. If you work in a shop that uses .Net, they are already expecting this distinction to be present

Comment: One of the drawbacks to a self-submit form is that if the user presses refresh, they will post the same thing again.

Comment: That is a negative. I typically use FW/1 one and do a  redirect. So even if they hit refresh, then no additional data is added

Comment: Re-submitting a POST request on refresh is a deliberate feature, unrelated to whether you submit to the same or a different URL. A [303 redirect](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.3.4) can be used in both cases to transform to a refresh-friendly GET request.