# More on 303 redirect

Tags: coldfusion, http-status-code-303

Yesterday, Peter Boughton mentioned that a [303 redirect can be used to transform to a refresh-friendly GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039221/should-i-self-submit-forms-or-submit-to-an-external-file/19071643?noredirect=1#comment29367823_19071643).

Q: How is this done? Suppose I have the form:

```
<form method="post">
<button type="submit" name="Save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Then how do you do a 303 redirect to keep the user from submitting the same thing by pressing F5?

Note: As of bootstrap 3, I'm now using button type=submit in favor of input type=submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<cflocation url = "newpage.cfm" addToken = "no" statusCode = "303">
```

See https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cflocation
 for more details

Comment: But then I would lose all my input field values, no? The reason I self-submit is in case something fails a validation.

Comment: You only use the `<cflocation>` if your post operation was successful. Otherwise, repopulate your form

Comment: Oh.  If there is something invalid, then I should put my form values in the session scope, do a cflocate back to the original form and repopulate the form values from the session scope?

Comment: If form is valid then do relocation, else repopulate. Session variables are not used for either operation

Comment: Oh, I got you. After the self post, redirect to a new page.  Or actually, do a cflocate back to the same page so that it's no longer a post.

Comment: But where does the 303 come in?

Comment: Are you asking a request lifecycle question?

Answer (score 0):

One idea that I'm playing with is not submitting the form at all.  Instead I change the button type="submit" to button type="button" and have JavaScript do an AJAX call to save the form and then do a window.replace so that when the user presses the back button, they don't have a long tail of browser history:

Here's my form:

```
<form method="post">
   <button type="button" id="Save">Save</button>
</form>
```

And here's my JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#Save',SaveClicked);
    function SaveClicked() {
        var local = {};

        local.data = {};
        local.data.method = 'Save';
        local.dataType = 'text'; // no return value.
        local.Promise = $.ajax('xxx.cfc',local);
        local.Promise.done(done);
        local.Promise.fail(fail);
    }
    function done(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        window.location.replace(window.location.pathname);
    }
    function fail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
    }
})();
```